# How to install wifi driver iwlwifi 4.2.0-16-generic

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers

I have no wifi driver on 14.04. I discovered by running a live usb of 15.10 that  wifi driver iwlwifi 4.2.0-16-generic works. I am wondering if there is a way to install this on 14.04? I have tried the obvious google searches but I'm still new at this and probably not looking in the right places.

I can't update to 15.10 because a program I need to use is not supported.

`lspci -nn | grep 0280` gives

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 79)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Nullsoft Scriptable Install System? I'm not really sure how I would do that? I can get internet over ethernet so I could use terminal and download the packages like normal, I just don't know where to get them from.

Comment: Sorry it's NDIS, detailed explanation here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

Comment: @Raphael  ndiswrapper is buggy and a last resort. It is not recommended.

Comment: Please start by editting your question to add details of your device from the terminal command: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`

Comment: What is your current kernel version `uname -r`?

Comment: @Pilot6 4.0.5-040005-generic, I tried upgrading it to take care of the wifi driver issues but no luck

Comment: Why not install a 4.2 kernel then?

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried and just got kernel panic on boot, I'll try reverting and upgrading again. Also, something I just noticed, on boot I very briefly get a message that says I'm missing firmware for iwlwifi.

Comment: Try my answer. Maybe you will also need firmware too.

Comment: @Pilot6 I ended up going for 4.3 which seems to have taken care of the driver issue for the wifi (and my trackpad which I thought was a totally separate issue). I don't see any immediate issues but if things start going screwy I'll downgrade and try the firmware option. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install backports from 4.3 kernel to Ubuntu 14.04.

I suggest removing un-official kernels and run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/09/03/backports-20150903.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-20150903.tar.gz
cd backports-20150903
make defconfig-iwlwifi
sudo make install
```

This should install a correct driver. But you will have to re-install it after each kernel upgrade by running the last three commands.

You may also need firmware for this adapter. You can install the firmware package from 15.10 this way:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.149.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.149.1_all.deb
```

or **you can install kernel 4.3.**